# How to get the key of an element, according another key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in that shape (when I print it):

```
{
 1:{'id':1,
    'name':'car'
    },
 2:{'id':2,
    'name':'train'
    },
    ...
 6:{'id':6,
    'name'='chocolate'
    }
}
```

I want to know, what is the best way, in Python, to get the id of an element? I want to know what is the chocolate's id. I'm quite new with Python, so I'm not used to with dictionary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a [Comprehension List](https://medium.com/@joshuapaulrobin/list-comprehensions-in-python-3-for-beginners-8c2b18966d93) expression like:

```py
myDict = {
 1:{'id':1,
    'name':'car'
    },
 2:{'id':2,
    'name':'train'
    },
 6:{'id':6,
    'name'='chocolate'
    }
}

#In python3
ids = [x['id'] for x in myDict.values() if x['name'] == 'chocolate' ]

#In python2
ids = [x['id'] for k,x in myDict.items() if x['name'] == 'chocolate' ]
```

The advantage of this approach is that you will manage cases where 'chocolate' is not in your dictionary (in which case you get an empty list) or cases where chocolate appears several times (and you will get a list of all the ids)

Comment: I got the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` I think it's because of the first level of my dictionnary

Comment: No, it is because you are using python2, which requires an expression some more longer: [x['id'] for k,x in myDict.items() if x['name'] == 'chocolate']

Comment: It worked! But I'm using Python 3.7 so I don't understand why Python 3 version failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

dd = {1:{'id':1,'name':'car'}, 2:{'id':2, 'name':'train'},6:{'id':6,'name':'chocolate'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(dd).T
df.loc[df['name'] == 'chocolate']['id'].tolist().pop()
```

EDIT:

version with no pandas:

```
[v['id'] for k,v in dd.items() if v['name'] == 'chocolate'].pop()
```

Comment: I think using pandas for this will be an overkill

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop for this,

```
d = {
 1:{'id':1,
    'name':'car'
    },
 2:{'id':2,
    'name':'train'
    },
 6:{'id':6,
    'name':'chocolate'
    }
}

for key, val_dict in d.items():
    if val_dict['name'] == 'chocolate':
        print(val_dict['id'])
```

You can use this one-liner list comprehension,

```
[val_dict['id'] for key, val_dict in d.items() if val_dict['name'] == 'chocolate']
```

Answer (score 0):

If asking the question "What is the id of chocolate" is something you need to do many times in your code, you should consider having a reverse dict. It will give you the best performance for the price of more memory allocation.

```
reverse_data = {'car':1,'train':2,'chocolate':6}
print(reverse_data['chocolate'])
```

output

```
6
```